# How can I remove time from datetime string in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

I have a Date time string `2021-12-12T11:11:00`. I want to remove the substring `T11:11:00`, so that I am left with `2021-12-12`.

Does anyone have any ideas? Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

```
 import 'package:intl/intl.dart'; //note --->>> import package

 DateTime parsedDateTime = DateTime.parse('2021-12-12T11:11:00');
 String formatDate = DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(parsedDateTime);
```

OUTPUT ->

```
 2021-12-12
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    String _date_and_time = "2021-12-12T11:11:00";

    String date = _date_and_time.split("T")[0];

    print("Date is : ${date}");
```